# Running raketask with cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake

all!
I try to rane rake-task in cron. Craken generate for me such crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /usr/local/www/vhosts/proj/www/current && /usr/local/www/vhosts/proj/www/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rake --silent RAILS_ENV=production my:rake_task >> ./tmp/log.log 2>&1
```

If I try to run this command manually, it works fine

```
cd /usr/local/www/vhosts/proj/www/current && /usr/local/www/vhosts/proj/www/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rake --silent RAILS_ENV=production my:rake_task >> ./tmp/log.log 2>&1
```

But after it runned by cron, I get in log:

> env: ruby18: No such file or directory

Prompt, please, where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to run the command manually as the user running the cron? I bet there is some problem with the bins not being in the env of that user.

Comment: Of course. When I tried to run this command manually, I ran it as the user running cron.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the environment variables (like PATH and maybe any other which are required by Ruby). Add the environment variables and the above commands into a shell script and retry.